# Speeding up website

Tags: performance

My website has poor speed both for desktops and mobile. We are not authorized to minimize images. What is the best option to speed this up? It is in WordPress. We have also used plugins like WordPress Total Cache.

Comment: This question is really too broad, and will likely result in [recommendations for external resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) like hosting services and plugins, which is considered off-topic here due to issues with spam and self-promotion. Note that we also don't do [individual website troubleshooting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here either.

Answer (score 1):

I've just scanned your website for performance issues and from what I can see the main issue here is a slow server response time.

One of the typical indicators of this is the white screen that you see when you type your URL in your address bar, as is the case for your website.

It simply seems to take the server 2+ seconds to do the back-end processing and start serving the page, resulting in a high Time To First Byte (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte).

Possible solutions:

- Remove unnecessary plugins that might be slowing down your server response time
- Tweak the settings of the TotalCache plugin or try a different plugin if this one doesn't give you satisfactory results.
- Switch to a different hosting company that is able to serve your website faster.